# ActionResult returns as an error in the ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, asp.net-mvc

So, I am trying to return an `xml` file from my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetXml(int id)
{
    var xmlBytes = _context.GetXml(id);

    if (xmlBytes == null) return View("NotFound");

    return File(new MemoryStream(xmlBytes), "application/xml", "file.xml");
}
```

This `Action` is perfectly called from this `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        window.location = url;
    },
    error: function(error) {  //error.responseText contains the actual xml string!
        alert("failed to download xml");
    }
});
```

However, instead of calling `success`, it goes directly to the `error` property. One interesting thing is that the `responseText` property from the `error` object contains the `xml` that I am looking for.

Could someone explain me what am I doing wrong and point me in the right direction to properly download the xml stream?

Thanks

Comment: Try including: `dataType: "xml",` in your ajax options

Comment: tried it already without success.

Comment: Try changing your response to: `return Content(xmlBytes, "text/xml");`

Comment: Same thing. `error.responseText` contains my xml

Comment: Is `xmlBytes` a string?

Comment: I think is more related to the mime type. Because using the same code to retrieve a `tiff` throws this message: 

`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/tiff:`

Comment: it is not. It is a `byte[]`. I am returning the memory stream. But, I converted it to a string before trying to return `Content()`

Comment: `error: function(error) { console.log(arguments); }` What is the error message.

Comment: @epascarello, the error message contains the actual xml string in the property `responseText`, `statusText: OK`, and `status: 200`

Comment: Did you look at all the arguments or just the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Yeah. 200 means an OK. That's why I am almost sure that is related to the dataType as @Hackerman mentioned. However, not working

Comment: The 3rd argument is the error message `function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. I am betting your XML is not valid. That is why I asked you to log `console.log(arguments);` to see the error thrown string.

Comment: @epascarello, it is a posibility that the xml is invalid...@Luis try this validator, for testing purposes: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: @epascarello, Hackerman. `xmlvalidation.com` said that no errors were found in the xml

Comment: So what is the 3rd argument in the error?

Comment: @epascarello oops. parseerror and invalid xml :D But why then the website approved it when I copied it? maybe returns with escape characters?

Comment: Look at the response from the network tab and see what is different.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello. It was an extra `\0` in the `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is classic issue where the status is 200 and the responseText has the output, but it is an error. Seems strange, but there is a reason for it.

If you were to look at the responseXML you are not going to see the xml document since it can not be parsed by the browser for some reason. Now jQuery auto detects the content type and sees it is XML, it sees the responseXML as null and throws it into the error state. If you log the arguments you will see the error message.

Now to debug this you can either copy the responseText from the console or inspect the response from the network panel. Putting it into your favorite XML validator and see if it picks up the errors. Common issues is the server sticking in hidden characters into the response which chokes the parser or the server returning junk before the xml document.